# There is a bijection between $\{ f: X \to Y \text{ continuous} \}$ and $ \tau_{_X} \times \tau _{_Y}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $\tau _{_X}$ and $\tau _{_Y}$ denote the topologies on $X$ and $Y$ respectively. I know that the statement in the topic is not true, but my feelings say that with a small modification, this will be true.

I want to keep the $\{ f: X \to Y \text{ continuous} \}$ part.

Maybe it would be true if $ \tau_{_X} \times \tau _{_Y}$ is replaced by $ \mathcal P  (\tau_{_X}) \times \mathcal P (\tau _{_Y})$?

**Q:** Is there a bijection between continuous functions $X \to Y$ and a set obtained by some operations on the topologies of $X$ and $Y$ ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could consider
$$\Phi[f](A_y) := f^{-1}(A_y) \in \tau_X$$
and look at $\mathrm{graph}(\Phi)$, but this is certainly not a surjection.

Comment: If $\tau_X$ is discrete, no matter what $\tau_Y$ is, the set of continuous maps $X\to Y$ is the same (all maps from $X$ to $Y$). So you can't “reconstruct” the topology of $Y$ from the set.

Comment: Take $Y =\{0\}$. Then there is only **one** (continuous) function $f:X \to Y$, which should allow you to conclude that your claim does not hold for most choices of $X$.